# A real life application for QR decomposition

Tags: matrices, applications, matrix-decomposition

I need to use the QR decomposition of a matrix for a real life application, (use it on a particular matrix form) and I have no idea what to do. Can you suggest me a real life application for this? thank you.

Answer (score 7):

See [this presentation](http://www.auburn.edu/~tamtiny/Xiamen%20U%202010%20Dec.pdf) for many examples.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. I would recommend adding a summary of the applications in case the link breaks one day.